# Spherical harmonic transform of complex-valued map?

Tags: python, healpy

Can healpy compute the spherical harmonic transform of a complex-valued map?

When I try this using `healpy.sphtfunc.map2alm`, there is no warning, but the function gives a_{l,m} only for m>0. This makes sense for real-valued maps, for which a_{l,-m} = (-1)^m * a_{l,m}^*. But for complex-valued functions, this symmetry does not exist.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asked Martin Reinecke, developer of HEALPix C++, here his answer:

What you can do is to run `map2alm` separately on the real and imaginary
parts of your map; the resulting `a_lm` coefficients are then simply
`a_lm,real + i*a_lm,imag`. If you want the coefficients with negative `m`
as well, you need to use the symmetry relation separately on `a_lm,real`
and `a_lm, imag` first and then combine them as described.
The reason why there is no direct support for complex-valued maps is
that this would make `a_lm` handling and spherical harmonic transforms
much more complicated, just to cover a case that is rarely needed (at
least in the area where `healpy` was originally used) and that can be
emulated by the workaround above if really needed.

All a_lm objects in Healpix and healpy are designed in a way that there
is the mentioned symmetry between `+m` and `-m`. For quantities with spin!=0
this symmetry doesn't exist either, so we introduce the linear
combinations `alm_E` and `alm_B`, for which it exists again.